# What is best implementation of useReducer hooks to replace redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm new to react hooks.i'm struggling with useReducer hooks.i'm confused about how to implement this hooks with context api to replace redux.Should i create only one useReducer in main App.js. or create multiple??
suppose i have an e-commerce project.Should i create only one big useReducer like this:

```
const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,{
  user:{},
  userLoading:true,
  cartItems:[],
  cartItemsLoading:true,
  wishListItems:[],
  wishListItemsLoading:true,
  featuredProduct:[],
  featuredProductLoading,
  // other properties...
})
```

Or create one for user,one for cartItems etc etc..??

Answer (score 0):

`useReducer` is not a replacement of `redux`. We can still combine both `useReducer` and `redux` in an application. It just depends on complexity of the project and its requirements.

For your query, we can have as many as we wish to have or just a single. It's your opinion how you implement it.

Here's my opinion:

If your project requires complex details to maintain, separate them accordingly. If your project is very simple, you may just use single reducer. As you are working on a e-commerce application, I would suggest you to maintain separation. For eg. Users, Carts, Products, etc.

Comment: ok.if i separate them accordingly should i pass them in one context provider in main App.js??

Comment: If you need to share the application  state, then just use one.